# How can I define macros using jade template engine?

Tags: html, pug, mathjax

When using jade with MathJax, I'm using a lot of such tags:

```
<script type="math/tex; mode=display">
  some math fomula
</script>
```

to generate math formula in web pages, so I will be writing

```
script(type="math/tex; mode=display").
  some math fomula
```

in jade each time I want to insert formula.

That is annoying, because the script tag is a bit too long and distracts me from the real content, and all such tags are the same.

So I'm wondering is there any way to "define" a tag in jade, so that I can simply write

```
math.
  some math formula
```

to generate the html above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jade mixins](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a14) to achieve something like that.

Comment: I considered mixin, but it seems that I can only write one line when inserting defined mixin. What I want to do is to have it accept a block of content and wrap that content with my defined tag.

Comment: Mixins support blocks. Just write a block following the invocation of the mixin and within the mixin simply use the keyword "block" to expand. You can even test if a block has been provided with "if block"